# Labels inside form fields with added Infield Top Aligned Labels

Tags: css

I'm looking to update our website and have the checkout form fields using labels inside the fields. I've read on various blogs this simple idea has some downfalls, such as the user forgetting what he/she was typing in that box in the first place.

So I stumbled across firebox.com checkout, which also uses infield top aligned labels, nullifying the above problem.  Also, on input, there are regular labels inside the field.

Has this idea/solution been previously documented?  I would prefer not to go through the source code of this site if there is a working example out there already!

Here is a screenshot of what I'm looking to do, some fields have been inputted already to show the result before and after.
[image: example screenshot]

Comment: The texts in this example look like they are absolutely positioned labels, with slightly different CSS depending on whether the input is focused or not. I don't think the source is that hard to understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Material](https://material.io/) design is what I think you are looking specially the part of the text fields.
No need to look through the code:

https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#

Here you can see all available options:

https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section

Hope it helps,

André

Comment: This is insanely helpful.  On the 2nd link you posted, the 'Text with floating label' is even better than I imagined. Thank you!

Comment: Glad for being helpful!

Answer (score 1):

What You are looking at is a sample of **[Google's Material Design components](https://material.io/guidelines/)**. The material design framework is meant to be part of AngularJS , but there are multiple CSS ways of achieving the same effects.

**[Here](https://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/IdGKH)** You can find a variant for Your task at hand.

And it uses generic markup:

```
<form>
  <h1>Material Design Text Input With No Extra Markup</h1>
  <input placeholder="Username" type="text" required="">
  <input placeholder="Password" type="password" required="">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Glad I can help. Cheers!